# jQuery .each() not iterating over array of strings as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Doing:

```
var tags = ["foobar", "hello", "world"];

$.each(tags, function(tag) {  
  console.log(tag);
});
```

Gives me an output of

```
0    
1   
2
```

Why is my output not

```
foobar   
hello    
world
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLzfS/1/)

Comment: here you go http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do this, the first parameter is for index:

```
$.each(tags, function(index, tag) {  
  console.log(tag);
});
```

Comment: Oh, hmm...i had no idea the first arg was the index. Thanks.

Comment: Or you can just do something like: `console.log(tags[tag]);`